# What is Mycroft implying when he says "Regrettably Lady Smallwood, my brother is a murderer"?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

Is Lady Smallwood actually willing to just let Sherlock go? But Mycroft doesn't agree because Sherlock murdered someone therefore must be punished whatsoever?

Answer (score 8):

She merely said

> "Hardly merciful Mr. Holmes."

I don't think she was suggesting to just let him go. Quite the opposite really. I think she *wanted* him to be detained in some sort of prison, she just didn't think he needed to *die*.

Earlier in the episode Mycroft told Sherlock about an assignment that would end with him dead in 6 months. At the plane, as they are saying their goodbyes, John asks Sherlock how long the assignment will take.

> "Six months, my brother estimates. He's never wrong."

He was being sent, at Mycroft's suggestion, to his death until

> Moriarty shows up at the end and Sherlock is called back to duty.